# how to store date from html form using datepicker in bean class property(java.util.Date)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, materialize

I am using materialized datepicker in my form and want to store that in my bean class property(java.util.date), but its showing null.

```js
$('.datepicker').pickadate
 ({ 
  //format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month 
  selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
 // closeOnSelect: true
  format : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
   hiddenName: true
 });
```

```html
<input type="date" id="dob" class='datepicker' ng-model="test.dateOfBirth" /> <label
        for="dob">Date of Birth </label>
```

here goes my Rest class:

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public String create(EmployeeBean emp) {
    System.out.println("in rest method...");
    System.out.println(emp.getSignum());
    System.out.println(emp.getDateOfBirth());





    System.out.println("Returned  here");
    return "{}";
}
```

I am getting other values but in date its showing null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you use the Materialize framework, they create the date as a string instead of the Date object. You need to take the string and convert it to a Date object if that's how you want to store it.

To do this in Java, you can use the DateFormat object first like this:

```
String strDate = "06/04/1992";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);

System.out.println(date);

// Output
Thu Jun 04 00:00:00 CDT 1992
```

Subsequently, this will now print using the default Date format and you will need to add a try/catch for the exception ParseException.

If you need to format the date back to a string, then you can do

```
String newDateObjectAsString = dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(newDateObjectAsString);

// Output
06/04/1992
```

The final code to test this would look like this

```
String strDate = "06/04/1992";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String newDateObjectAsString = dateFormat.format(date);

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(newDateObjectAsString);
```

**Edit (Javascript version)**

Does something like this work for you?

```
var parts ='04/03/2014'.split('/');
//please put attention to the month (parts[0]), Javascript counts months from 0:
// January - 0, February - 1, etc
var mydate = new Date(parts[2],parts[0]-1,parts[1]);
```

I found it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835394/6294139

Comment: can't it be done at jquery or js level?? Because  parameter passed in rest method is bean class reference. I am populating my bean on basis of form details and cannot change dob type to String in bean class. Parameter passed in rest method is bean class reference.

Comment: I have edited my post to include a piece of code and a link to another article I found on stackoverflow. Also, is it not possible to use my solution in the EmployeeBean getDateOfBirth() method?